# Install Heroku CLI on Mac showing exited with 128 error

Tags: git, macos, github, heroku

I am trying to install Heroku CLI using this command

```
brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku
```

But I am getting this error

```
akshaybandivadekar@Akshays-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku     

==> Tapping heroku/brew
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/heroku/homebrew-brew'...
akshaybandivadekar@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Error: Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/heroku/homebrew-brew /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/heroku/homebrew-brew --origin=origin --template=` exited with 128.
```

I have checked my GitHub profile and my ssh key setup is successful there.
I am able to clone any public repo using ssh setup for eg

```
git clone git@github.com:lodash/lodash.git
```

But this command is not work

```
git clone https://github.com/lodash/lodash.git
```

I am done with all commands given in this article =>
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

But still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, any SSH URL which does not use 'git' as its remote user would not work.
So `akshaybandivadekar@github.com` cannot be used.

Second `https://github.com/lodash/lodash.git` is an HTTPS URL, not an SSH one.
If you want to use your private SSH key, you would need:

```
git clone git@github.com:lodash/lodash.git
```

If you want to force using SSH:

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

But you need to be sure that you have the right to access that repository.

Also, if akshaybandivadekar@github.com is part of the dependencies:

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "akshaybandivadekar@github.com:"
```

Comment: But suppose some of the commands which have the dependency of another GitHub repo, then that case it uses HTTPS URL and it breaks
=>brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku
==>
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/heroku/homebrew-brew'...
akshaybandivadekar@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
Error: Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/heroku/homebrew-brew /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/heroku/homebrew-brew --origin=origin --template=` exited with 128

Comment: @AkshayBandivadekar I have edited my answer to address your comment. Try first the last command I mention there.

Comment: I have tried the last command, and still facing the same issue

Comment: But I have tried the 2nd last command(git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
), and it works, thank you so much @VonC, you save my day, Really appreciate it :)

Comment: @AkshayBandivadekar Great! Well done!